# How to play swf file on Google TV device?

Tags: android, flash, google-tv

I have tried this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
        String pathFlash = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "flash/1.swf";
        File file = new File(pathFlash);  
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "flash/*");  
        startActivity(intent);
```

But it crashes the application because android cannot find the proper activity to play a flash file.

I there any other way to play flash files on the google tv device?

Comment: Flash is no longer supported on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can play flash video in a limited way using Chrome (Flash 10 and lower currently works). Try passing the local uri to the flash file to Chrome - it might work - I have not tried it.
You could also try creating a local html file with the flash object embeded into it an load that in Chrome (local flash file reference in the html - pass the uri of the html using an intent)